# How to act differently if input is a multiple of x?

Tags: python

My program asks for an input from the user, but I want to reject any multiples of 26 (or if 0 is entered) and ask for the user to input again. I can't figure out how to do this; I'm guessing it's something to do with dividing the input by 26 and getting an integer.

The current code is:

```
  ValidInput = False  
  while ValidInput == False: 
    try: 
      Key = int(input('Enter the amount that shifts the plaintext alphabet to the ciphertext alphabet: ')) 
    except: 
      print("Sorry, that isn't an integer. ") 
    else: 
      ValidInput = True 
  return Key
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your actual question, but I want to point out that using a flag variable like `ValidInput` is generally discouraged in Python. Use `while True` and `break` instead!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the modulo operator:

```
if Key % 26 == 0:  # If Key / 26 returns no remainder
    # Key is therefore divisible by 26
```

Comment: And, conveniently, `0 % 26 == 0` so it also does the right thing when the input is 0!  :-)